# MySQL 5.7 - Error on linked list query - expression was expected near "("

Tags: mysql, list, syntax-error, expression

Here is my query to display the orderd list :

```
SELECT  @r := (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    t_list
        WHERE   parent = @r
        ) AS id
FROM    (
        SELECT  @r := 0
        ) vars,
        t_list
```

Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 115)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 115)

This for the second FROM.

(https://explainextended.com/2009/03/25/sorting-lists/)

Comment: What is your MySql Version?  It is working fine for me here. Are you running this in some client? Havent you forgot the `;` at the end of the query before running it?

Comment: MySQL 5.7 and you ? error is after the FROM on (SELECT  @r := 0 ) vars, t_list;

Comment: My version here is 5.6. There is nothing wrong with this query. I believe that must be something with the client you are on.